# Extension for Windows Admin Center (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, wac

i would like to write an extension for Windows Admin Center
(it is a Powershell script that loops though all clusters-> through all nodes -> and finally lists up all VMs with their data( CPU, RAM...)
The powershell script is finished, but how do i insert it into the WAC surface ???

Answer (score 1):

you need to build a tool type extension.. here is where you can begin looking into
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/extend/prepare-development-environment

Comment: thankyou for your answer (and sorry for my late reply)

Comment: i tried to build an extension but i get this error message:

Comment: appErrorHandler -- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'powerShell')                                           So it doesnt work, although i did it exactly as told in the MIcrosoft Tutorial

Comment: return this.appContext.powerShell.run(this.session, script3)

Comment: looks like that MS have not updated their repository for long... thats why there are lots of errors related to dependencies and I guess your error is just one of them. Please try to reach MS to let them updating their repository

Comment: Thx!   Can i do that? I mean, can i download it  ("git clone ...") and then update the repositories by myself